# How do I set an Android View's transparency with animation?

Tags: android, opacity

I need to set the initial transparency for a `TextView`, but I don't know how to do it. On iPhone/iOS, it can be done easily with the alpha property. On Android, I've tried to set the alpha using `AlphaAnimation` but it's no good -- it doesn't work. It just returns to 100% alpha when the animation ends.

```
AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0.2f);
anim.setDuration(5000);
textView.startAnimation(anim);
```

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Just use anim.setFillAfter(true).

Comment: Thanks man! That worked :) Though it's pretty strange that it cannot be done without using animation...

Answer (score 3):

You can set the alpha channel directly in a color value that you assign to the TextView.  See [Available Resource Types](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html).

Comment: It's not the same. That way I can't animate alpha changes

Comment: You aren't asking for animation in the alpha value so don't be surprised if we don't tell you how to do it.