# Leaving an Android Animation at it's end state

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to do an animation that takes a button (with a custom background image and system text) and fades it out. That works fine, actually. The issue is after the animation it goes back to it's initial state. I want it to animate and stay that way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0.2f);
anim.setDuration (5000);
textView.startAnimation (anim);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
```

That should work.

My answer is 'stolen' form [android.View transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180677/android-view-transparency)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't mention one important point. I want it left at a semi-transparent state. The animation fades it to 0.71 alpha, and that's where I'd like it - so the View.GONE doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: See if that helps - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setFillAfter(boolean)

Comment: There is one more ')' at the end of previously posted link.

Comment: Well in those docs it refers to "setFillAfter" in a way that sounds like what I need but it doesn't work. I think it may be because views don't have an alpha property? I mostly work with iPhone and on that platform setting something to half-transparent is as easy as view.alpha = 0.50; but is it the case that Android has no way to do this?

Comment: For anyone (like me) reading this some time down the line, please be aware that the code posted above does indeed leave the state at the specified alpha, and doesn't hide it completely. I think there were some edits. :)